L-functions of quartic/sextic twists of elliptic curves
For an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with $j$-invariant equal to 0 or 1728, LMFDB tells us that $E$ admits a sextic or a quartic twist. I wanted to know how we can relate the L-function $L(E/\mathbb{Q})$ to the L-function of its sextic/quartic twist. In the quadratic twist, we can twist by a quadratic character, but I am not sure if this is the case for sextic/quartic twists.
This answer by Wuthrich (also this) suggests we can relate the L-function (over $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_3)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$) of $E$ with its cubic twist via a character on a cyclic group of order 3.
I am interested in the case when $E$ has additive reduction at an odd prime $p$ and its sextic or quartic twist has good reduction at $p$. In this case, as per LMFDB, we twist by a suitable power of $p$ to get another elliptic curve which has good reduction at $p$. A relation between their respective associated cusp forms would also be helpful!
(Additionally, I would be grateful if someone could explain what it means when we twist by say p^3; for the quadratic case, I understand it is the discriminant of the quadratic extension we twist by)
This is my first post here, please let me know if I should add different tags or rephrase the question. Thank you!
